# How do I fetch data from the database so I can create dynamic elements through javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

So I have this model right here that looks a bit like this

```
public class UserAccount : IdentityUser
    {
        public string Username{ get; set; }
    }
```

and I also have a view that looks something like this

```
    @model Myproject.ViewModel.TheViewModel
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Welcome";
    }

<div id="theContainer"> <div/>
```

And inside that view I want to generate a paragraph using JavaScript (not inline, I want to use a seperate file) 
So I created a js file and I then created a function that works like this.

```
var container = document.getElementById("theContainer");
var newParagraph= document.createElement("p");

//I could add attributes by doing newParagraph.addAttribute(..)
// but you will read why that is an issue soon

container.appendChild(newParagraph);
```

As you can see that would generate a empty paragraph element to the element with the id `theContainer` within the document.

And this is where the issue occurs.
I have a database setup for my ASP.NET project and I have a couple of entries in there.
I would like to fetch the `Username` property of those entries and then generate `<p/>` elements on the fly dynamicly. The issue is that I have no idea how to fetch the data from the database and use it with my JavaScript.

So my question is, how do I fetch data from my database and use it to generate elements?

Comment: Funny enough, your wording is itself the answer. There's a [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) (it lacks IE support, so you might also consider another library that uses XmlHttpRequest (AJAX)). Then you just need to expose an action method from a controller that returns JSON. You can do this in ASP.NET MVC, though if you plan on doing a lot of it you might also look into ASP.NET Web API. You could also just add the data to your model, render that model in the view to a hidden field in the markup and use JS to retrieve the value from the hidden field.

Comment: Would I have to create a new project for the Web API? That seems like a bit much doesn't it?

Comment: No, you can host Web API in the same project as your MVC project. Web API is just a NuGet package that you install. Then you add a bit of config (to enable routing to your Web API controllers etc) and they'll happily coexist. Of course, if you do this you'll likely discover at some point that it can be better to not do MVC at all, instead using some front end framework (such as Vue, React, or Angular) that then talks to your Web API. But you can just dabble your toes in it by adding Web API into your existing site if you wish.

Comment: So ASP.NET Web API and React, Vue or Angular.. Hm.. Could work!

Comment: Of course it can work! Many, *many* sites are using architectures like that. You could consider that the "modern" way of building a site. If you wanted to look to the future (which is always fuzzy), then [Blazor](https://blazor.net/) is my best guess. Of course, it's experimental and who knows if it will gain marketshare and develop a health ecosystem. But it has the advantage of not needing JavaScript and you can code in a great .NET language such as C#, and you can reuse your code on both client and server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options. You can embed the value into your view, so that it gets rendered in the markup. Or you can have your JavaScript call out to your server to retrieve it.

---

Let's start with embedding it in the view. We'll assume that Username is a property of your model.

In your Razor,

```
@Html.Hidden(m => m.Username)
```

Then in your JavaScript, you can retrieve the value from the hidden input.

```
var username = document.getElementById("Username").value;
```

This technique has the unfortunate advantage of polluting your view with a lot of hidden field. You could just shove your entire model into a JSON string and add that to a hidden field, but that's messy too.

---

Similar to using a hidden field, you could have paste the value directly into a script placed in the Razor view.

```
<script>
    var username = '@Model.Username';
</script>
```

Then you can consume that variable from your other scripts.

---

Or you can fetch the value from your server. You can make use of the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) (be warned, it's not available in Internet Explorer without a pollyfill). Let's assume you have an endpoint on the server that returns a User model with a Username property as JSON.

```
fetch('/user/1')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(user) {
    var username = user.Username;
  });
```

(I may have gotten the syntax wrong, I haven't worked with the Fetch API much myself)

---

If you don't want to use the Fetch API, you can use the older [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) API to communicate back to your server side. Using the API directly stinks (it's not super friendly) so we often use an abstraction layer on top of it, such as [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Assuming the same server side as in the previous example:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "/user/1",
  dataType: "json"
})
.done(function(user) {
  var username = user.Username;
 });
```

---

For your server side, MVC controllers can return JSON:

```
public ActionResult User(int id)
{
    var user = userRepository.GetUserById(id);
    return Json(user, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

---

Or you can install [Web API](https://www.asp.net/web-api) into your existing ASP.NET project (it can live alongside MVC):

```
public IHttpActionResult User(int id)
{
    var user = userRepository.GetUserById(id);
    return Ok(username);
}
```

Comment: If I start using Vue for instance, won't I lose features like how ASP.NET Core MVC has `Identity` for roles and what not?

Comment: @MarkDenom Are you using ASP.NET Core MVC? I thought you were using non-Core, because of the way your question is tagged. In that case, MVC and Web API have been combined, and you don't even need to install a separate package. Anyways, you can still use Identity. There's several ways to go about it. You can keep your login MVC based but have the rest of your site use Vue. Or you can implement [JWT tokens](https://medium.com/@ozgurgul/asp-net-core-2-0-webapi-jwt-authentication-with-identity-mysql-3698eeba6ff8).

Comment: Yeah I am using `Core` I thought I added that tag, my bad. I think using the Hidden method will work I'm gonna play around with it

Comment: @MarkDenom The tag for that would be [asp.net-core-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp.net-core-mvc/info). And you wouldn't use the asp.net tag, you'd use [asp.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp.net-core/info).